# How can I merge or concatenate two sequential models using Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset with two text fields which after tokenization I have made two sequential models which I am trying to combine or merge but i am facing errors while merging.

I have built two sequential models already and I am trying to merge them without using Keras Functional API.

```
# define the model
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size_1, embedding_size, input_length=MAXLEN))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(op_units, activation='softmax'))

# define the model
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size_2, embedding_size, input_length=MAXLEN))
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(op_units, activation='softmax'))

merged = concatenate(axis=1)
merged_model=merged([model1.output, model2.ouput])

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-79cf08fec6fc> in <module>
----> 1 merged = concatenate(axis=1)
      2 merged_model=merged([model1.output, model2.ouput])

TypeError: concatenate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

I am expecting an approach without using Keras Functional API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `concatenate()` functions requires you to specify the models to be concatenated.

`merged = concatenate([model1,model2],axis=1)`. However, the axis has to be axis=-1 (You may use whatever is appropriate in yopur case.)

Your code can be further written in a functional way as below:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(vocabulary_size,embedding_size), dtype='float32')

model1=Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_size)(inputs)
model1=Flatten()(model1)
model1=Dense(op_units, activation='softmax')(model1)

model2=Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_size)(inputs)
model2=Flatten()(model2)
model2=Dense(op_units,activation='softmax')(model2)

merged = concatenate([model1,model2],axis=-1)

model=Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=merged)
```

Comment: I have made the changes and now I am getting a value error.

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

Comment: I am using sequential because the two models that I have developed are text columns which I have further tokenized to solve an nlp problem. And when any column is tokenized then building models using Keras Functional API becomes difficult. Please share if you have any idea of using the functional api for text tokenized columns.

Comment: Hi, the answer seems really useful but I have two vocabulary sizes. Which one shall i use while giving the inputs?

Comment: Actually, you are suppose to use the sequence length (the number of tokens).

Comment: `inputs = Input(shape=(token_length,embedding_size), dtype='float32')`. You are not supposed to use the size of our  vocabulary(The number of words in your dictionary). Instead, use the number of max token used in sequence. Suppose you want to have 200 maximum tokens in your sentence, use it.

Comment: Done that. But while fitting the model I am getting an error.

Comment: # fit the model
model.fit([trainseqs,trainseqs_1], 
          [y_train,y_val], 
          epochs=5,
          validation_data=([testseqs,testseqs_1],[y_test,y_valid]),
          verbose=2)

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3575, 300)

Comment: Shall I also change the vocabulary size to token_length in the embedding layer too?

Comment: What is your input, how have you tokenized it?

Comment: I have two text fields as my input which I have tokenised

Comment: Can you give the sample?

Comment: can you please gimme your mail id? I will send the entire problem statement and the code

Comment: You can share your's n I will mail you.

Comment: My mail id is moinakd21@gmail.com

Comment: Please reply I badly need your help

Answer (score 0):

`model1.output` and `model2.output` are tensors. I assume two models share the same input. There are several ways, here is a solution within Keras dealing with these models. You can use `keras.layers.Concatenate` and `keras.models.Model`:

```
inp = Input([MAXLEN,])
out = Concatenate()([model1(inp), model2(inp)])
model = Model(inp, out)
```

If they don't share the same text inputs. You can also do it this way:

```
inp = [model1.input, model2.input]
out = Concatenate()([model1.output, model2.output])
model = Model(inp, out)
```

This by default, concatenate outputs on the last dimension, which happen to be the same `axis=1`.

In any case, concatenating softmax outputs seems very odd. If there are two different texts with two different predictions, you need two outputs. You don't need to concatenate them. You can have outputs as a list, and ignore the concatenation:

```
inp = [model1.input, model2.input]
out = [model1.output, model2.output]
model = Model(inp, out)
```

If you got the outputs in other types such as numpy array, then it's a different situation.

Comment: I have two text fields predicting one target which is multi class

Comment: so why are you concatenating two softmax layer? shouldn't you have one single softmax layer and concatenate two models before the softmax?
If you have 10 classes of targets, with concatenation it is 20 classes which their probabilities don't sum up to 1!

Comment: I don't understand. Could you clarify? :)